# Ruby on Rails: "no such file or directory" with logger.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm attempting to run a RoR app locally for the first time.  I've started the server and I get the following error (after WEBrick starts):

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /dev/null (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I try to run rake db:migrate and I get the same error:

```
    ** Execute environment
    rake aborted!
    No such file or directory - /dev/null
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `initialize'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `open'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `create_logfile'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:594:in `open_logfile'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:549:in `initialize'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:314:in `new'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:314:in `initialize'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/logger.rb:72:in `initialize'
```

I'm running on a Windows machine, in case it helps.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

```
> ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

> rails -v
Rails 3.2.0
```

Comment: I installed it with an exe from rubyinstaller.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/null file is specific to unix, there's no such file on Windows.

Comment: So the real question is, why is it trying to open /dev/null ?

Comment: to fix this you need to find where in code is the `Logger` instance constructed and change the first parameter to some real file on your system. Beware, that if something pointed out to `/dev/null`, the developer wanted it to dissapear, so be sure to clear that file you set to log on windows from time to time.

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed it :).  The project was developed on a *nix machine so I should have looked for that in the config files.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @farnoy 's answer.

although from the trace it looks like that it might be thrown from rails framework stack or ruby stack. usually it is caused by application developer making wrong assumptions about the environment.

in my case, it is some of the App script file specify '/dev/null' as log file causing the cross platform break.

just grep 'dev/null' in your application folder and modify accordingly.