# No such file or directory - /dev/null (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm having a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334138/ruby-on-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-with-logger-rb) to this gentleman here.

I've been trying to run a cucumber feature via a rake task. And I've been picking up the specified error in the title.

Here's a full backtrace. And my ruby version. (When I attempted to run the rails version command, I got "command not found".

```
$ rake features:all --trace
** Invoke features:all (first_time)
** Invoke features:watir_webdriver (first_time)
** Execute features:watir_webdriver
c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile watir
Using the watir profile...
No such file or directory - /dev/null (Errno::ENOENT)
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:34:in `initialize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:34:in `open'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:34:in `initialize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:124:in `initialize'
c:/code/page-object/features/sample-app/sample_app.rb:12:in `new'
c:/code/page-object/features/sample-app/sample_app.rb:12:in `start'
c:/code/page-object/features/support/ajax_text_environment.rb:6:in `block in run'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumbe...]
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:104:in `run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in define_task'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => features:all => features:watir_webdriver
```

And ruby version

```
 ruby -v
 ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
```

Any help would be infinitely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the other question's answer and comments. Specifically, do you have a Logger configured in your code (or config) somewhere?

Comment: I don't, and I'm not entirely sure how to actually configure it. It was suggested in the other comments section to do so, but I'm not 100% sure how. Otherwise I'd be all for it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try searching for `/dev/null` in your repository (e.g. `git grep /dev/null/` if you're using git).

Comment: I actually figured it out. There was a configuration setting in the application I'm working on in one of the slightly obscured files. It set the path of the logger to "/dev/null". I just changed it to "logger.txt" and it works now.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: See? Easy. How about an upvote :)?

Answer (score 9):

the `dev/null` was in `config/initializers/quiet_assets` and I replaced `dev/null` with `logger.txt`

Comment: great awnser :D i'd +2 this if I could

Answer (score 1):

if you are working on the same application on *nix and windows you could replace `'/dev/null'`

with `RUBY_PLATFORM != 'i386-mingw32' ? '/dev/null' : 'NUL'`

for me it was in quiet_assets.rb and I replaced

`Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')`

with

`Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new(RUBY_PLATFORM != 'i386-mingw32' ? '/dev/null' : 'NUL')`

Comment: I'm using an example from webmachine-ruby and this patch works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. There was a configuration setting in the application I'm working on in one of the slightly obscured files. It set the path of the logger to "/dev/null". I just changed it to "logger.txt" and it works now.